# "fetch" is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, junit, htmlunit

I have this code that I am testing with HTMLUnit:

```
function fetchIt() {
    var response = fetch('https://httpbin.org/get');
    var json = response.json();
    console.log(json);
    return json;
};
fetchIt();
```

But throws

```
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "fetch" is not defined.
```

How can we use `fetch` with HTMLUnit, JUnit testing?

`fetch` as in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: from what I know it is part of the browser API?

Comment: HTMLUnit is the browser I use for unit testing

Comment: How do you know HTMLUnit supports fetch at first place?

Comment: Can you please open an issue in the HtmlUnit bug tracker. And if you like HtmlUnit is available at GitHub - every contribution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the code with *HtmlUnit* means you are not in a browser with the [fetch capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility).

You should include the [polyfill for fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch) in your page or make it available in the unit test context.

Comment: Where can I get the JS files to include in the browser html?

Comment: btw link is broken